# Why java allows run() to throw Unhanlded Exception while restricting Handled ones?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

It is sayed that the run does't throw Handled Exceptions. JVM simply ignores them. So I threw UnHandled Exception (ArithmeticException). But the same thing happened for it as well.
I know that it is rediculous to try to catch the excpetion from a thread that has been started by the catch clause marked as XXX. Because the excution may already passed that line.

But I wanna know why java allows run to throw Unhanlded Exception while restricting Handled ones and what is happening additionally when run() throwing Unhandled Exception?

**Parent Thread**

```
public class Parent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Child   child   = new Child();
        Thread chThread = new Thread(child);

        try {
            chThread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) { // XXX mark
            System.err.println("XXX");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Child Thread**

```
public class Child implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() throws ArithmeticException{
            method0(); // line 8
    }

    public void method0(){
        int i = 0/0; // line 12
    }
}
```

**java.lang.Thread**

```
public class Thread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run(); // line 619
    }
    }
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at seperateStacksPerThread.Child.method0(Child.java:12)
    at seperateStacksPerThread.Child.run(Child.java:8)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Did you mean to say checked/unchecked?

Comment: exactly NPE! checked - Handled , unchecked - unhandled.

Comment: Do you think run method of a thread should be allowed to throw checked exceptions? if it can, who will handle it? Checked Exceptions are exceptions which (can be/should be) handled by the program. But for Unchecked exceptions you cant do anything about it, and they could happen anywhere in a program.

Comment: no i think the other way around. Unhandled must also be restricted to throw. Or if not why?

Comment: in java any method (with or without throws clause) can throw unchecked exceptions. This is because unchecked exceptions are rarely predictable(thats why they are unchecked). Offcourse you can write  if(i==0) throw ArithmaticErrorException(); but a better code will have this problem wrapped in a checked Exception (may be IisZeroException) and handle it(try catch) because you know what to do when i is zero. Well if you dont expect zero at all then no need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `run()` does not include a checked exception. As a result you can not override it to throw a checked exception (when you `override` you can never be more restrictive).
But throwing an unchecked exception is allowed as it is not part of the signature (no one is required to catch it).
When you throw the arithmetic exception it is part of the stack trace of a *different thread*.
Notice that it says:

`Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

And **not**: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

Now why are checked exceptions not allowed, it is a design decision and I think it is because no one can catch them anyway as a thread is a *separate flow of excecution*.

Comment: then why it is allowed unhadled exceptions to throw?

Comment: @NamalFernando.. Because `unchecked exception` are not checked by compiler. You can add extra unchecked exception to throws clause of overriden method, but they would be ignored by the compiler.

Comment: @NamalFernando:Because as you can understand during your flow of execution it is bound that you could potentially get an exception. Some of the exceptions can be caught and handled within that thread e.g. can not connect to a server but could try again in a couple of seconds but some exceptions can not be handled at all e.g. after 5 retries it is not possible to connect to the server and there is nothing you can do so you can just throw the unchecked exception to indicate the error and that thread will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *all* methods may throw unchecked exceptions.

Next, the simple reason `run()` doesn't throw checked exceptions is there's no one there to catch them! The method is called from within the started thread as its "main" method - it's the top level entry point. There's nothing above it to deal with an exception, so there's no point in declaring a method that throws an exceptions.

Comment: `there's no one there to catch them!` I don't really agree on this. E.g. if you use an executor it executes each `run` inside a `try/catch(Throwable)`. So it is not so much as there is no one to catch it, as much as it is a different flow of execution that makes it not possible to catch it in the code in the OP.